# How to perform migration when adding a property to a Realm object

Tags: objective-c, realm, realm-migration

I'm receiving crash reports like the following: 
`Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'UserProfile.interfaceLanguage' has been added.`

I understand how to perform a migration in general, but I don't know what is required when you add a property.  `interfaceLanguage` is not strictly required for the app to work and it will be fetched from the server eventually.  I suppose I could set it to some value during the migration, but that seems a bit pointless.

Moreover, I thought this case was handled by default: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations

> if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
>       // Nothing to do!
>       // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
>       // And will update the schema on disk automatically
>     }

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything in your migration block when adding properties, Realm will do the migration automatically. All you have to do is increase your schema version by one and increase the number (1) in `if (oldSchemaVersion < 1)` as well.

Comment: The fact that I got a crash here means that either 1. non-automatic migration is actually required or 2. there's a bug in realm.  I don't see how adding an empty `if` statement to the migration can fix anything.